# Why this post build event does not work in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a post build event which works in Visual Studio 2012 but does not work in Visual Studio 2008, the script is as following:

```
xcopy "$(SolutionDir)..\ABC\defaultSettings.xml" "$(SolutionDir)$(SolutionName)\$(OutDir)" /Y
```

I am having a smart device project which is using `.Net Compact Framework` but I don't think it has anything to do with this.

Any idea why the post build event is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

The macro names seem correct. Perhaps the issue is that the .xml is not there.

Have a look at this [article](http://geekswithblogs.net/dchestnutt/archive/2006/05/30/80113.aspx). It explains how you can get more meaningful messages out of the post build event failures.

You could also try to get rid of the quotes and use Copy command instead.